# codeigniter's base_url() function in pure php

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is there are a way to get base url (url_helper in codeigniter) like codeigniter using only php.

My project address looks like

```
http://localhost/proj1/
```

and it can be any name
how to get the URL which will give the same base URL on any file in the structure tree, depending on all situations like `http://` or `https://`

Comment: I've provided the script and explained that codeigniter uses so you can implement it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Setup a file **config.php**

```
<?php

   define('base_url','http://localhost/proj1/');

?>
```

On every page include config.php. Like this :

page1.php

```
<?php

 include_once('config.php');

 echo base_url;


?>
```

For more info about `define();` [**read this**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php)

**Edit 1 :**

if you want you can try this also :

```
<?php

       define('base_url','http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/');

    ?>
```

Or if your using sub folder then :

```
$root = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$root .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
define('base_url',$root);
```

**Edit 2 :** Try this one :

```
define('ROOTPATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/');


// installed in the docroot?
if (realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) == $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])
{
    define('ROOT', '/');
}
else
{
    define('ROOT', substr(ROOTPATH, strlen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])+1));
}


$url = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https://" : "http://") . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . ROOT;

define('base_url',$url);

echo base_url;exit;
```

Comment: how can it be portable? if i host it somewhere else the address would be something else...

Comment: You have to change the URL in config.php file if address has changed

Comment: Since you are using constant `base_url` on every page so if you change the URL in config.php file it will effect on every page

Comment: i know i can... but way without that? like codeigniter guesses automaticaly

Comment: Codeigniter guesses automatically ? In codeigniter also you have to set a base_url inside your config file

Comment: Codeigniter will have it set up in a config file somewhere then use autoloading to include all the files. It still needs to be set somewhere as @RakeshShetty suggested

Comment: use codeigniter more often... u'll see it working with empty base_url string in config.php

Comment: yes... thats what im saying... how to do that using php?

Comment: @Hanze see my EDIT 2.

Comment: @Hanze I have tested and it return the result what you looking for

Comment: **``$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`` working under iis**, but it has the following issue - [$_SERVER](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Comment: **Edit 1 & Edit 2 yields url like `http://[::1]/codeigniter_demo/index.php/news/1`**

Answer (score 0):

Or if you want it in php and not codeigniter try the $_SERVER variables of php

```
     echo "http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
```

[Link](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Comment: Then just keep the substr between $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] with the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

Comment: Or $url = str_replace($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],"", $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']); and you are done. If you think thats not a good solution i would like to explain it a bit further if you have the time in order to understand why. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is how codeigniter does it, straight from the git repository:

https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter

**CodeIgniter / application / config / config.php**

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Base Site URL
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| URL to your CodeIgniter root. Typically this will be your base URL,
| WITH a trailing slash:
|
|   http://example.com/
|
| If this is not set then CodeIgniter will guess the protocol, domain and
| path to your installation.
|
*/
$config['base_url'] = '';
```

**CodeIgniter / system / core / Config.php**

```
/**
 * Class constructor
 *
 * Sets the $config data from the primary config.php file as a class variable.
 *
 * @return  void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->config =& get_config();
    log_message('debug', 'Config Class Initialized');

    // Set the base_url automatically if none was provided
    if (empty($this->config['base_url']))
    {
        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']))
        {
            $base_url = (is_https() ? 'https' : 'http')
                .'://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
                .substr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], 0, -strlen(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])));
        }
        else
        {
            $base_url = 'http://localhost/';
        }

        $this->set_item('base_url', $base_url);
    }
}
```

You should provide a base url in the config file, I presume this will then get autoloaded by codeigniter and the `base_url()` will return this value.

Whenever config.php gets instantiated it checks to see if the base url has been configured in the config.php, if it hasn't it will try and guess by checking the host, protocol base name of the script etc. Then the set_item method is called, which would set $config['base_url'] to whatever the logic above has determined to be the base url